# How to avoid jobs name nesting with GitHub Actions reusable workflows?

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-reusable-workflows

I have a GH workflow with multiple jobs that are executed after each. These jobs are defined in other files.

```
name: pipeline

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  Init:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/init.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      ...
  Build:
    needs: Init
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      ...
```

init.yml

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      ...
    outputs:
      ...
jobs:
  Init:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    outputs:
      ...
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

GitHub displays the job name of the original workflow file and the job name of the reused workflow file nested into each other in the title. I would like to avoid this.
In the navigation bar on the left, the nested job name however is not shown.

[image]

How can I avoid this name duplication and show only one job name?

Comment: I was googling for thins and this seems the only result, i see no answers nor comments, but wondering if you figured it out @Cristopher ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I consider this a bug in GH as it's shown in the sidebar but not the breadcrumb. So fine for me right now and I wait till GH fixes this.